# win32 - Dialog inside .dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dialog

I want to a create .dll, which shows some dialog.

In my .dll I have this code:

```
HWND hDlg = CreateDialogParam(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_RANKING_DIALOG), NULL, msgProc, NULL);
if (!hDlg)  {
    ShowError(GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    return false;
}
```

`ShowError` calls Message box and `GetLastErrorAsString()` just calls standard `GetLastError` and converts to string.
I have this output:

> The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.

Then I have a standard win32 Window application and there I call method, which calls the mentioned code.

```
DialogTest test;
test.showDialog(); // calls functionality from .dll
```

What I am doing wrong? Do I need to link resource files to .dll?

I am using Visual studio 2010 and `dialog` is specified in my resource file (.rc).

Comment: You are passing `NULL` in the `hInstance` argument to `CreateDialogParam()`. That means the dialog resource wil be looked up in the executable that has loaded your DLL, not in the DLL itself. You should pass the `HINSTANCE` associated with your DLL instead.

Comment: I have tried use GetModuleHandle(0) instead of NULL but it doesn't helps. So how can I get the HINSTANCE of dll.

Comment: It's passed as the first argument to your `DllMain()`.

Comment: Ok, and If I don't have a DLLMain()? Because my .dll is called from Java code. They use System.LoadLibrary() in java. Does this cause to run my DllMain() and then I can save the hInstance to global variable and with it create dialog?

Comment: @JaroKollár GetModuleHandle(0) will do the same thing as NULL.

Comment: @Jaro, yup, if you define a `DllMain()` entry point, it will be called and you will be able to persist the `HINSTANCE` into a global variable.

Comment: @JaroKollár to add to the above, it doesn't matter what loads your DLL; it's Windows that calls DllMain when a DLL is loaded, Java or otherwise. (Think about it: what if you could bypass DllMain? Then DLLs wouldn't be able to do initialization!)

Comment: Unrelated to the resource error, `ShowError(GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());` is a bug waiting to happen. I assume that `GetLastErrorAsString` returns a `std::wstring` or `std::string`. This is a temporary, and as soon as `c_str()` returns, it goes out of scope. You are then passing a dangling pointer into `ShowError`.

Answer (score 8):

The error code and message are accurate: The resource cannot be found where you instructed the system to go looking for it: The executable image that was used to start the process, not your DLL. The behavior is documented (see [CreateDialogParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645445.aspx)):

> *hInstance* [in, optional]

> Type: **HINSTANCE**

> A handle to the module which contains the dialog box template. If this parameter is NULL, then the current executable is used.

Since you have the dialog template stored inside your DLL, you will have to pass the `HINSTANCE` that identifies your DLL. There are a number of ways to get the correct value, but passing `NULL` or `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` won't work. Both of these return the module handle to the executable image that started the process (not your DLL).

The easy solution: Pick the *hInstance* passed into your [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx) and store it in a global variable for later use.

```
HINSTANCE g_hInst = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved ) {
    switch ( fdwReason ) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInst = hinstDLL;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The robust solution: This solution can be used anywhere, in a DLL, an EXE, or a static LIB. Only down-side: It relies on undocumented features of Microsoft's linker. Don't worry, though, it won't fail silently.

```
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#define HINST_THISMODULE ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase)
```

`HINST_THISMODULE` will always hold the correct value, regardless of where it is used.<sup>1)</sup>

The same can be achieved using official interfaces ([GetModuleHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx)) as well. The following solution can be used from an EXE, a DLL, or a static LIB as well, so long as you make sure to compile and link the function into the respective module:

```
HMODULE GetCurrentModuleHandle() {
    HMODULE hModule = NULL;
    GetModuleHandleEx( GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
                       (LPCTSTR)GetCurrentModuleHandle,
                       &hModule );

    return hModule;
}
```

This returns an `HMODULE`, not an `HINSTANCE`. This is not an issue, though, since they are the same thing<sup>2)</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup> From [Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483)

<sup>2)</sup> [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903)

Comment: Thanks, all solutions looks correct, but I try this and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You specified NULL as the first parameter to `CreateDialogParam`. If you want to load the dialog resource file from the Win32 Window Application, you should use this instead:

```
HWND hDlg = CreateDialogParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_RANKING_DIALOG), NULL, msgProc, NULL);
```

However, if you want to load it from the DLL itself, you should replace the first parameter with the HINSTANCE parameter from the DllMain entry point function of the DLL.

Comment: Nope, `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` returns the module associated with the current executable, not the DLL.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for pointing that out, I believe Ive corrected the answer

Comment: Yes, but the call to `GetModuleHandle()` is not necessary. You can simply pass `NULL` to `CreateDialogParam()` if you want to load the resource from the current executable's module.

Comment: [That's historical baggage, and not necessarily good practice.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/14/10377977.aspx)

Comment: @andlabs, that's what the blog (from 2012) says, but the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645445(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly says `A handle to the module which contains the dialog box template. If this parameter is NULL, then the current executable is used`

Comment: @EdwardClements both statements are true. It is historical baggage that still works. The same way rotary phones still work, though you probably shouldn't be installing rotary phones in new office buildings.